# what is the 'symbolSize' argument in the callbacks of 'SymEnumSymbols' from dbghelp?

Tags: c, dbghelp

I'm using the `symEnumSymbol` function from `dbghelp` library to get details about any `malloc` symbols in an executable. One of the arguments that I need to pass is a callback functoin with the following signature:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumSymProc( 
    PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo,   
    ULONG SymbolSize,      
    PVOID UserContext);
```

And I want to extract all the data I can from those parameters.

The Windows Dev Center provide this insufficient description about the second:

> *SymbolSize*:
>   The size of the symbol, in bytes. The size is calculated and is actually a guess. In some cases, this value can be zero.

I've implemented the callback in the following way:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumSymCallback(
PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo,
ULONG SymbolSize,
PVOID UserContext)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(UserContext);
    printf("Hello from symEnumSymbols!\n");
    printf("%08X %4u %s\n", (unsigned int)pSymInfo->Address, SymbolSize, pSymInfo->Name);
    return TRUE;
}
```

and I call `SymEnumSymbols` with those arguments:

```
if (!SymEnumSymbols(
    GetCurrentProcess(),            // handler to the process.
    0,
    "*!malloc",         // combination of the last two lines means: Enumerate every 'malloc' symbol in every loaded module - we might change this...
    EnumSymCallback,        
    NULL                // argument for the callback.
))
{
    printf("SymEnumSymbols failed :-(\n");
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    printf("SymEnumSymbols returned error : %d\n", error);
    return FALSE;
}
printf("SymEnumSymbols succeeded :-)\n");
```

and I got this output: [EDIT: I just added enumeration for `free` ]

```
Hello from symEnumSymbols!
766300D0   16 malloc
Hello from symEnumSymbols!
0F9BE340   32 malloc
Hello from symEnumSymbols!
7662E0F0   48 free
Hello from symEnumSymbols!
0F9BDFA0   80 free
SymEnumSymbols succeeded :-)
```

As you can see, in the first time `malloc` symbol size is 16 and in the second 32. I'm not sure how I got two `malloc` in the first place since my executable supposed to have only one (I wrote the source) but assuming the other one is coming from the compiler or something - what are those sizes? and **why they are different**?!

I can guess it specify a 32 bit command or a 16 command, but I realy don't have a clue and this not maiking sense with `free` results. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looking through the code I use for stack traces I always pass 0 for that parameter and never use it. I do use the PSYMBOL_INFO::Size member to figure out if a basic type is a short or an int, but that seems to be all.

Comment: okay, thanks for that. but here I got wierd and unconsistent sizes: 16, 32, 48, 80...
I hope you can help with that because I'm confuse...

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nc-dbghelp-psym_enumeratesymbols_callback).

> [in] SymbolSize
>
> The size of the symbol, in bytes. The size is calculated and is
> actually a guess. In some cases, this value can be zero.

That descrpition looks confusing. I personally don't use SymbolSize but gather specifically ask for the symbol length when requried.

There are different types of symbols like Function symbols to UDT symbols (describes the layout of a struct or class).  The SymbolSize makes sense for UDT symbol but for a function symbol I have no idea what the SymbolSize may mean.  The code size of the function itself?  The fact that it says "is actually a guess", I would take that it's not that useful.